# Best way to compare every index of one list to every other index of that same list

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, performance

This is just a general algorithmic question, but I was wondering if there is a more efficient/faster way of comparing every element of a list to every other element of a list without duplicate checking.

I have an implementation which is straightforward

```
        for item in list:
            for comparator in list:
                if comparator == item:
                    pass
                else:
                    # do something...
```

But the problem with this is that there's going to be a duplicate check & doesn't scale well. Is there an methodology that can do this more efficiently or more quickly?

Comment: Look into the `itertools` module.

Comment: I haven't done Python in a while, but is there an `nlogn` way, like in other languages, such that the 2nd loop only looks at elements further than the current one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do better than just double loop and avoid comparing with the same index. We can also eliminate 'mirrored checks' (e.g. if we check a==b we don't need to check b==a). This is what `combinations` from `itertools` produces. So each time we add another item to the input we get another n-1 possible comparisons.

The example below generates the combinations of length 2 and creates tuples of the two numbers and the result of an equality check.

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> [(a, b, a == b) for a, b in combinations([1,2,3,1,2], 2)]
[(1, 2, False), (1, 3, False), (1, 1, True), (1, 2, False), (2, 3, False), (2, 1, False), (2, 2, True), (3, 1, False), (3, 2, False), (1, 2, False)]
```

Comment: This is fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To avoid comparing duplicates, use `enumerate()` and skip the case where the indexes are the same.

```
for i, item in enumerate(list):
    for j, comparator in enumerate(list):
        if i == j:
            continue
        if comparator != item:
            # do something
```

There's no way to avoid the scaling problem -- you have to loop over every pair of elements to achieve your goal. That's inherently O(n^2).

Answer (score 0):

```py
for i in list1:
    if i in list2:
        continue
    else:
        # do something
```

not sure if this is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Parallel computing using multiprocessing/threading might make it faster.

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
    
def action(enum_elem):
    index, item = enum_elem
    for index2, comparator in enumerate(list1):
        if index == index2:
            continue
        if comparator != item:
            # do something
            
pool = ThreadPool(5)
pool.map(action, list(enumerate(list1)))
```

Comment: I don't know if you might know why, but I'm sure this method is making it go slower. Unless you know of something else that might affect it?

Comment: You are right. Multithreading might not be a good idea here because in python, multithreading tends to be slower for CPU bound operations.